# monaca IDEでERROR whitelist rejectionが起こる

Tags: monaca

monaca IDEでjquery mobileのスマートフォンアプリを作っています。ブログからJSONを受け取り表示しているのですが、記事中のyoutubeの埋め込みがiOSだと下記のようなエラーになります（Andoroidでは表示されます）。

```
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://www.youtube.com/embed/ab5SOhu..'
```

PhoneGapのExternalHostsに*を追加することを試みましたが、monaca IDEではPhoneGap.plistにアクセスできないのか見当たりません。あとconfig.xmlにが記載されているのは確認しました。
おわかりになられましたら、ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

config.xmlに以下を追加してみると良いかもしれません。

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。config.xmlに<access origin="*" />書いてありました。しかし上記のエラーが起こっています。

Comment: monacaデバッガーでは上記のエラーでしたが、デバッグビルドしたら正常に動きました。ありがございました。